# webpack, react and babel: Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm following this [tutorial](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack_and_react/) on webpack and react. It seems every other step I run into an error because of some update to npm or node or react or <insert js thing>

But this time... I'm getting an error from either webpack or react:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
```

Here's the code:

*app/index.jsx*

```
import './main.css';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

*app/components/App.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from './Note.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Note />;
  }
}
```

*app/components/Note.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>Learn Webpack!</div>
```

I'm using

- react        0.14.6
- react-dom    ^0.14.6
- node         5.3.0
- npm          3.5.3
- babel-core   ^6.4.5
- babel-loader ^6.2.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find anything on this. I am also facing the same

Comment: Facing the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

I have been fighting this issue for a while. The problem is with circular dependencies - if you have a class that extends another, but they both import a class that imports each other, then the super expression will simply resolve to undefined. Here's an example of how it can be triggered:

A.ts

```
import './C';

class A extends B {
}
```

B.ts

```
import './C';

class B {
}
```

C.ts

```
import './A';

// Library code here
```

In this situation, class A was considered to be extending `undefined` because the dependency tree became circular (as C required A which required B which required C, etc) and it seems like the engine simply "gives up" and resolves the superclass constructor to undefined. In my case, I moved some of the functionality I needed from `C` so that `B` did not import it anymore. It broke the circular dependency - and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Oh wow, just realised this was posted 4 years ago :D

Answer (score 1):

If the problem happens when applying Webpack's optimization through **Terser** plugin, try with **UglifyJS** instead:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.optimization = {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  };

  return config;
};
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to define the constructor in your app class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Note from './Note.jsx';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <Note />;
  }
}
```

Also, your Note component should probably be set up similarly to App:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Note extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Learn Webpack!</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That wasn't it tho. I'm leaning towards something being wrong with webpack or babel's configs because doing some logging no `console.log`s are getting fired off at all. If I comment out everything in the _app/index.jsx_ file it still gives me the same error

Comment: And Note should work perfectly fine as a steateless function component `export default () => <div>Learn Webpack!</div>`, btw.